# Finding missing number in a sequence

Tags: c#, math, missing-data

I need to find one missing number, from a sequence of numbers

such as

4 8 12 16 __ 24.

I need to find the missing number. How would I do that programmatically?

the numbers and the missing placement are not static, so they should be able to change.

Hope it is possible.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem. What have you tried?

Comment: It is impossible because there are infinite number of ways you can build your logic. What you can do is to limit it to only several methods of building sequences which will make it a trivial loop-through..

Comment: I'd also say this is a math.stackoverflow question because there is no particular programming aspect here.

Comment: Isn't it just `difference / 2`?

Comment: @Simon Whitehead: I think the OP wants the program to find the missing number of an arbitrary series of numbers, (if I understood correctly, that is).

Comment: @pcnThird that's exactly what I wan't it to do ^_^

Comment: assuming there is only one missing number you could determine the pattern using different groups in the array and then determine which group doesnt follow the pattern of the other groups

Comment: @chancea please do tell me how :)?

Comment: https://www.or-exchange.org/questions/5897/how-to-find-a-pattern-in-a-sequence-of-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some silly linq like this silly example :)

```
var numbers = new List<int>{4, 8, 12, 16, 24, 28, 36};
int first = numbers.First();
int last = numbers.Last();

var missing = Enumerable.Range(first, last).Where(n => n % first == 0).Except(numbers);


Returns:
20
32
```

*-Bracing self for downvotes-*

Comment: this assumes that you'll that your first element is equal to the difference between all the elements in the list.

Comment: In an interview (which is where this problem is usually seen), you would probably be told to make a more general solution, i.e. not using Linq. Also it would need to work with negative and positive values.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that it is always an Arithmetic Progression, you can use the formula:

```
an = a1 + (n - 1) * d
```

being a1 the first element, d the difference between 2 elements and n the position to calculate, in your case:

```
an = 4 + (5 - 1) * 4 = 20
```

Check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression